# Looking for help to turn a large string into many smaller variables

Tags: python, string, discord

I am having issues with some code I am writing, I am currently getting this output:`{'footer': {'text': 'Item Type: Sellable'}, 'thumbnail': {'width': 75, 'url': 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 'proxy_url': 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/c4teYBjoGAhxnygEZ5F2GlHWzReCIg_xEOX1PPtZdIQ/https/cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 'height': 75}, 'color': 15684432, 'type': 'rich', 'description': "This item's purpose is to be collected or sold. Nothing more, nothing less.\n\n**BUY** - Not able to be purchased\n**SELL** - ⏣ 1,680 (multiplier included)\n**TRADE** - 2k - 7k", 'title': '**Common Fish** (516 owned)'}`, I would like to only have the last part: (516 owned). My goal is to be able to have the 516 be a separate variable that I can use in other portions of the code. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Do you have that as a string, or do you have this as an object?  As an object, obviously, all you need is `obj['title']` with a little string processing.

Comment: It is a string, is there an easy way to convert it?

Comment: Yes, if it is a string, it is JSON.  You can use the `json.loads()` method to convert it to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the output you shared is already a python dictionary, you can call the `title` key and then use a regular expression to extract the number you want.

```py
import re

results = {
    'footer': {'text': 'Item Type: Sellable'}, 
    'thumbnail': 
    {
        'width': 75, 
        'url': 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 
        'proxy_url': 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/c4teYBjoGAhxnygEZ5F2GlHWzReCIg_xEOX1PPtZdIQ/https/cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 
        'height': 75
    }, 
    'color': 15684432, 
    'type': 'rich', 
    'description': "This item's purpose is to be collected or sold. Nothing more, nothing less.\n\n**BUY** - Not able to be purchased\n**SELL** - ⏣ 1,680 (multiplier included)\n**TRADE** - 2k - 7k", 
    'title': '**Common Fish** (516 owned)'
}

var = int(re.search("\d+", results["title"])[0])
var
>>> 516
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for helping as I am very new to coding! I do notice that you specify the width, if I wanted my code to be applicable to any number of lengths of string, would this still work?

Comment: This is coming up with an error, `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`.

Comment: He should have typed `results` instead of `d`, and you should have been able to figure that out.

Comment: updated the answer. I updated the variable name at the last moment to `results`.